# findQuery - Emberfire error

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, firebase, emberfire

I am getting this errror:

This is the line I am using to get data -->  return this.store.find('food', {feel: 2});

I am using,

Ember      : 1.10.0

Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.12

EmberFire  : 1.3.3

jQuery     : 1.11.2

Error while processing route: index Assertion Failed: You tried to load a query but your adapter does not implement `findQuery` Error: Assertion Failed: You tried to load a query but your adapter does not implement `findQuery`

I'm am not sure if this is Ember.js specific or if the root of the problem is coming from Firebase? Any tips?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does emberfire 1.3.2 implement findQuery method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546256/does-emberfire-1-3-2-implement-findquery-method)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546256/does-emberfire-1-3-2-implement-findquery-method

Answer (score 1):

EmberFire 1.3.3 did not support `findQuery` but the latest release (1.4.1) does. Details are here: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-03-09-new-emberfire-features.html